# In Python 3 (tkinter) is it possible to animate a frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, tkinter

I have a tk window with some packed frames and I want a new panel to slide up from the window bottom (and do the reverse movement when getting out of the screen). This is the code I am using to make this panel show up statically at the intended position (its placed in a position relative to `self.statusframe` that is packed at the window bottom):

```
self.bottomframe.place(in_=self.statusframe, relx=1,  y=0, anchor="se", relwidth=1, bordermode="outside")
self.bottomframe.lift()
```

Is there an easy way to animate a placed tkinter frame so that it seems to be sliding up into the intended position?

Comment: You can do it using the standard pattern for tkinter animation (using `after`), modifying the coordinates with `place` on each iteration.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `for y in range(-100,1):
                self.bottomframe.place(in_=self.statusframe, relx=1,  y=y, anchor="se", relwidth=1, bordermode="outside")
                self.bottomframe.after(100)`

Comment: Ok. I think I get it. I made a few experiences with it, adjusting the range to `range(-9,1,3)` and changing `y=y` to `y=-y`. Now it comes from the desired direction into the desired position. However, I did not use `after` as I was not able to figure out how it worked. The animating only appeared on screen anther I added a `.update()` in the `for` loop. However, it's very slow, at least in my system, and that's why I reduced the animation to just a few frames. Is there any way to make it draw and animate faster?

Comment: Experimenting a little more, I noticed that using `y=y**2` in the `.place()` arguments seems to allow a wider movement without taking more time. That's what I intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to post an update that might be useful to those who come across this question, after reading Bryan Oakley's comment and digging a little more, in this case I ended up using this code, that I believe does what I intended:

```
for y in range(-10,1,2):
    self.bottomframe.update()
    self.bottomframe.place(in_=self.statusframe, relx=1,  y=y**2, anchor="se", relwidth=1, bordermode="outside")
```